# how to keep loading screen for more than 4 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to keep the loading screen for at least 4 seconds. But the timer at the end isn't working here's the code

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
 const preload  = document.querySelector('.preload');
 preload.classList.add('preload-finish');
}, 4000);
```

Comment: the third argument is meant to provide options like set listener only once and change the event phase. if you want to run your code after a certain time you should use `setTimeout`

Comment: `window.addEventListener` doesn't take a timer like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout`

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
 const preload  = document.querySelector('.preload');
 setTimeout(()=>{preload.classList.add('preload-finish')}, 4000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your 2nd parameter is a true or false for bubble/capture
use setTimeout instead

```
    function fName(){
        ...do something;
    }
    document.setTimeout(function_name(), 4000)
```